# How to solve javax.naming.NameNotFoundException at this code

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, java-ee-6

I make a Ejb project in netbean 7.3 with jboss-7.1.1 Final

In Ejb module i have these:

LibrarySessionBeanRemote.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint.stateless;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface LibrarySessionBeanRemote {
void addBook(String bookName);
List getBooks(); 
}
```

LibrarySessionBean.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint.stateless;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;


@Stateless
@Remote(LibrarySessionBeanRemote.class)
public class LibrarySessionBean implements LibrarySessionBeanRemote {

List<String> bookSelf;    

public LibrarySessionBean() {
this.bookSelf = new ArrayList<String>();
}

@Override
public void addBook(String bookName) {
bookSelf.add(bookName);
}

@Override
public List getBooks() {
return bookSelf;
}
}
```

and I make a client with java application project type

```
package client;

import com.tutorialspoint.stateless.LibrarySessionBeanRemote;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;


public class EJBTester {

BufferedReader brConsoleReader = null;
Properties props;
InitialContext ctx;
{
    props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "testuser");
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "test");
        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
        props.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,   org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.class.getName());
    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext(props);
    } catch (NamingException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    brConsoleReader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EJBTester ejbTester = new EJBTester();

    ejbTester.testStatelessEjb();
}

private void showGUI() {
    System.out.println("**********************");
    System.out.println("Welcome to Book Store");
    System.out.println("**********************");
    System.out.print("Options \n1. Add Book\n2. Exit \nEnter Choice: ");
}

private void testStatelessEjb() {
    try {
        int choice = 1;

        LibrarySessionBeanRemote libraryBean =
                (LibrarySessionBeanRemote) ctx.lookup("LibrarySessionBean/remote");

        while (choice != 2) {
            String bookName;
            showGUI();
            String strChoice = brConsoleReader.readLine();
            choice = Integer.parseInt(strChoice);
            if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.print("Enter book name: ");
                bookName = brConsoleReader.readLine();
                libraryBean.addBook(bookName);
            } else if (choice == 2) {
                break;
            }
        }
        List<String> booksList = libraryBean.getBooks();
        System.out.println("Book(s) entered so far: " + booksList.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < booksList.size(); ++i) {
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + booksList.get(i));
        }
        LibrarySessionBeanRemote libraryBean1 =
                (LibrarySessionBeanRemote) ctx.lookup("LibrarySessionBean/remote");
        List<String> booksList1 = libraryBean1.getBooks();
        System.out.println(
                "***Using second lookup to get library stateless object***");
        System.out.println(
                "Book(s) entered so far: " + booksList1.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < booksList1.size(); ++i) {
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + booksList1.get(i));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (brConsoleReader != null) {
                brConsoleReader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
}
```

but i have this exception

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: LibrarySessionBean/remote -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.LibrarySessionBean.remote
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:97)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:178)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleServerMessage(Protocol.java:127)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingServerV1$MessageReciever$1.run(RemoteNamingServerV1.java:73)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call an EJB you should not use the remote-naming project, but the remote EJB-invocation as described in https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

Your JNDI name will look like:

```
context.lookup("ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClassName)
```

appName and distinctName are empty in your case (no EAR).
See the example in the provided link.

Comment: In this specific tutorial case:

NewSessionBeanRemote libraryBean1 = 
                 (LibrarySessionBeanRemote)ctx.lookup("/EjbComponent/LibrarySessionBean!com.tutorialspoint.stateless.LibrarySessionBeanRemote");

Answer (score 4):

JNDI address format has changed significantly on JBoss 7. Related documentation can be found [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project#RemoteEJBinvocationsviaJNDI-EJBclientAPIorremote-namingproject-RemoteEJBinvocationsbackedbytheremotenamingproject).

Try replacing `LibrarySessionBean/remote` with:

```
app-name/module-name/LibrarySessionBean!com.tutorialspoint.stateless.LibrarySessionBeanRemote`
```

where:

> **app-name** = the name of the .ear (without the .ear suffix) or the
> application name configured via application.xml deployment descriptor.
> If the application isn't packaged in a .ear then there will be no
> app-name part to the JNDI string.
>
> **module-name** = the name of the .jar
> or .war (without the .jar/.war suffix) in which the bean is deployed
> or the module-name configured in web.xml/ejb-jar.xml of the
> deployment. The module name is mandatory part in the JNDI string.

Answer (score 0):

The Following code is an Standard a bit adapted to your example. Always Worked. Just remember to change de values in "**appName**" and "**moduleName**"

That's it

```
    props = new Properties();
    final String appName = "PackageEARProjectName";
    final String moduleName = "PackageProjectName";
    final String sessionBeanName = "LibrarySessionBean";
    final String viewClassName = LibrarySessionBeanRemote.class.getName();
    Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
    jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
     jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote://localhost:4447");
     // username
     jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "testuser");
     // password
     jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "test");
     // This is an important property to set if you want to do EJB invocations via the remote-naming project
     jndiProps.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
     // create a context passing these properties
     Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
     // lookup the bean
     LibrarySessionBeanRemote LibrarySessionBean =(LibrarySessionBeanRemote)context.lookup(appName+"/"+moduleName+"/"+sessionBeanName+"!"+viewClassName);
```